# Apache PIG - Full result of GROUP BY not passing into user defined function

Tags: apache-pig, user-defined-functions

So I am a beginner with Apache PIG. I am trying to group some data and then send the results of the grouping to the user defined function for further processing. So the data is a csv and looks like this

```
DAY;STATION;HOUR;TEMPERATURE
```

My PIG file code:

```
REGISTER /path/to/jar/myUdf.jar;
weather_data = LOAD 'file:///path/to/file/weather_small.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS (date:chararray, station:int, hour:int, temperature:Bigdecimal);
by_hour = GROUP weather_data by (hour, date);
DUMP by_hour
to_udf = FOREACH by_hour GENERATE myUdfs.Test();
STORE to_udf INTO 'myoutput' using PigStorage(',');
```

My user defined function code, not doing anything yet cause I am not getting all the data:

```
package myUdfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class Test extends EvalFunc<String> {
    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        return tuple.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the output of the DUMP command. this is the actual result of the group by call.

[image: Output of dump command]

And finally this is the data in the final reducer output file

```
((24,11/23/2000),{(11/23/2000,24)})
((24,11/23/2013),{(11/23/2013,24)})
((24,11/27/2009),{(11/27/2009,24)})
((24,11/30/2000),{(11/30/2000,24)})
((24,12/10/2013),{(12/10/2013,24)})
((24,12/13/2009),{(12/13/2009,24)})
((24,12/14/2007),{(12/14/2007,24)})
((24,12/23/2008),{(12/23/2008,24)})
((24,12/24/2007),{(12/24/2007,24)})
```

As you can see, the outputs are different. The station and temperature information is not being sent to the user defined function. But it is present in the original bag which resulted from the group by call.

***I need to send all the information to the user defined function. So the temperature and station information needs to pass to the udf as well***

Sorry for the long post but this was the only way I could explain the issue clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass anything to your UDF function and actually it' a bit surprisingly that it passes group automatically

Try

```
to_udf = FOREACH by_hour GENERATE myUdfs.Test(weather_data);
```